# scrollHeight not working with position:absolute

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to retrieve the body's `scrollHeight` in order to reset the size of a div with id="background1".  If in my external css I set that id to `position:absolute` the `scrollHeight` always returns 0.  If I set it to `position:relative` `scrollHeight` gives me the correct value.  There are of course many more selectors in the css one other of which is set to `position:absolute` - leaving it as such doesn't change the above behavior.  The code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function getElement(elem)  {

     var art;

     if ( document.all ) {                  // this is the way old msie versions work      
       art = document.all[elem];  
     }
     else if ( document.layers ) {          // this is the way nn4 works    
       art = document.layers[elem];
     }
     else if ( document.getElementById ) {  // this is the way the standards work    
       art = document.getElementById( elem );
     }

     return art;
}

function toggleArticleDisplay(elem)  {

  var artArray = document.getElementsByTagName("article");

  for(var i = 0; i < artArray.length; i++)  {
     artArray[i].style.display = "none";
   }

   var art = getElement(elem);
   art.style.display = "block";

   var bg1 = document.getElementById("background1");
   bg1.style.height = "550px";  

   var b = document.getElementById("potoococha");

   alert(b.scrollHeight);

   bg1.style.height = (b.scrollHeight >= window.innerHeight) ? 
           (b.scrollHeight+20) + "px" : window.innerHeight + "px";
 }

</script>

</head>

<body id="potoococha" onLoad="toggleArticleDisplay('homeText')">

<div id="background1" style="height:615px;"/>
```

And now the css :

```
div#background1  {  position         : absolute;
                    left             : 45px;
                    top              : 0px;
                    z-index          : 1;
                    width            : 50px;
                    background-color : rgba(182,181,91,1.0); }
```

Merely changing that position to relative makes the javascript function return the correct `scrollHeight` but I need this as `absolute` for other reasons.  Does `scrollHeight` not work if some element is absolutely positioned?  As I said there is another later absolutely positioned element which doesn't have any effect on `scrollHeight`'s return value.  Only this element which is the first child of the body element seems to be a problem.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kinda a dirty hack, but you could try to do this:

```
bg1.style.position = "relative"; 

var savedHeight = b.scrollHeight;

bg1.style.position = "absolute";
```

Not sure if that'll work, but maybe give it a try.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved the issue controlling the variable

```
document.scrollingElement.scrollHeight
```

instead of

```
document.body.scrollHeight
```